# How to Pivot big data in Python

Tags: python

I have a table with 140 million records

I have aggregated data 
My data look like this

```
filename code frequency
1054968  A837 3
1054968  F939 2
9899223  W821 8
3775859  A837 5
..
..
..
```

I want to Pivot the data to look like this

```
filename  A837  ...  F939 ...  W821 ...
1054968    3          2         0
9899223    0          0         8
3775859    5          0         0
```

I use this method

```
df_pivot = df_features.pivot(index='filename', columns='code', values='frequency')
```

It works fine with around 100,000 records but when reach 1M

I get this error

```
    "Unstacked DataFrame is too big, " "causing int32 overflow"

ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow
```

How can I do that pivot? (total number of columns after pivot should be around 36,000)

Comment: There are some answers to this question already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56790261/pandas-int32-overflow-cant-bulid-a-pivot-table).  One option (which falls under the "use a different library" category is https://dask.org/.

Comment: pandas is little difficult to handle this big dataset.. you can try Dask or Datatable from H2O.ai